# Jsonschema: array of uniquely identified elements, ordered, completed with other elements with constraints

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to create a schema for data that has these constraints:

- it is an array of objects;
- 2 of these objects are uniquely identified, have to be in the data only once, and should stay ordered (the first one should be before the last one);
- other objects (that follow some constraints) can be present 0 or more times, at some defined places in the array (here between the first and the second required elements).

->I simplified the problem. In practice I have more that 2 objects, and "other objects" with different constraints placed at multiple places in the array.

I thought of the `oneOf` property, here is what I tried:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Schema01",
    "description": "",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "oneOf": [
            {   
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "const": 1
                    },
                    "val01": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [ "id", "val01" ]
            },
            {
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "properties": {
                    "copy_id": {
                        "const": 4
                    },
                    "val01": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [ "copy_id", "val01" ]
            },
            { 
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "const": 2
                    },
                    "val12": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [ "id", "val12" ]
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

But this schema do not fullfill all my needs.

**It validates these data samples correctly**:
->all required objects are there (1 and 2), and there is 0 or more (here 3) other elements that fullfill the defined constraints, and placed between id 1 and 2.

```
[
    { "id": 1, "val01": "object 1" },
    { "copy_id": 4, "val01": "copy object 1" },
    { "copy_id": 4, "val01": "copy object 2" },
    { "copy_id": 4, "val01": "copy object 3" },
    { "id": 2, "val12": "object 2" }
]
```

and

```
[
    { "id": 1, "val01": "object 1" },
    { "id": 2, "val12": "object 2" }
]
```

**It doesn't validate these data samples (it's the exepected behavior)**, the first because there is an unallowed attribute, and the last because there is an unknown element (id: 3):

```
[
    { "id": 1, "val01": "object 1", "val02": "object 1" },
    { "id": 2, "val12": "object 2" }
]
```

and

```
[
    { "id": 1, "val01": "object 1" },
    { "id": 2, "val12": "object 2" },
    { "id": 3, "val01": "object 1" }
]
```

**But it validates these three data samples, that all should be invalidated**: the first because there misses a (should-be) required element (id: 2), the second because one of the required elements appears two times (id: 2), and the last because the order is not correct (copy_id elements should appears between id 1 and id 2, in this example).

```
[
    { "id": 1, "val01": "object 1" }
]
```

and

```
[
    { "id": 1, "val01": "object 1" },
    { "id": 2, "val12": "object 2" },
    { "id": 2, "val12": "object 44" }
]
```

and

```
[
    { "id": 1, "val01": "object 1" },
    { "id": 2, "val12": "object 2" },
    { "copy_id": 4, "val01": "copy object 1" },
    { "copy_id": 4, "val01": "copy object 2" },
    { "copy_id": 4, "val01": "copy object 3" }
]
```

So there are (at least?) three constraints missing:

- One of the required elements (id 1 or id 2) cannot appears two times;
- Each required elements (id 1 or id 2) should appears in the data;
- The order of the elements should be important.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying ? Or maybe that json-schema cannot do this kind of thing at this time ?

One option could be to edit the data before verification, to replace the main array with an object, where the id is the key and the remaining part of each object is the value. But I would loose the order of the elements.

If it is possible to find a solution for the two first missing constraints and not the third one (and without needing to edit the data), I would be happy too. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So there are (at least?) three constraints missing:
>
> - One of the required elements (id 1 or id 2) cannot appears two times;
> - Each required elements (id 1 or id 2) should appears in the data;
> - The order of the elements should be important.

OK, let's take each requirement one at a time...

> One of the required elements (id 1 or id 2) cannot appears two times;

There is a JSON Schema keyword `uniqueItems`, but it only looks at each element in the array as a whole. You cannot do this sort of data integrity checking with JSON Schema.

> Each required elements (id 1 or id 2) should appears in the data;

This CAN be done, but I suspect what you're asking is more than it appears. Do you really want to check the array contains at least one object with an id of `1` and another with `2` (those specific values)? Or is your requirement more dynamic than that in nature? (Please leave a comment, and I'll be happy to help further.)

> The order of the elements should be important.

If you wanted the first element to have an id of `1` and the second to have an id of `2`, that would be possible, but it looks like you're asking to allow other objects to appear inbetween, which would not be possible to validate.

JSON Schema looks to validate the structure and format of your JSON. It sounds like your requirements are to do with business logic / application logic, which JSON Schema genrally doesn't cover. This is extreamly unlikely to change, so you would need to write code to check these sorts of business logic requirements.

Comment: Yes, I want to check the array contains at least one object with id=1, and one with id=2 (these values). My schema is generated dynamically on the basis of another object: the task I'm trying to do is to check that an object has not been altered "too much" (some changes are allowed, but there are constraints). So my idea was to generate a jsonschema schema on basis of the original object, and then verify the modified object with the generated schema.
Thank's for your answer! I will do this task without jsonschema.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting use case! I'm intrigued. But yeah, I don't think JSON Schema is the right tool for the job here.